# Need to help about font

Tags: fonts, logo

What is the name of this font I'm trying to find but i couldn't. I shall be very thankful if someone suggest me about it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Muhammad. We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This font is [Danube Pro](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cheapprofonts/danube-pro/):

[image]

For future reference, try using any or all font identification websites before posting a font-identification question. Here are the [GD.SE site requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) that contains a list of said resources and other helpful tips for these types of queries.